# Create java list from user input

Tags: java, list

I have a bit of a unique problem to solve and I'm stuck.

I need to design a program that does the following:

1. Inputs two series of numbers (integers) from the user.
2. Creates two lists based on each series.
3. The length of each list must be determined by the value of the first digit of each series.
4. The rest of the digits of each series of numbers becomes the contents of the list.

Where I'm getting stuck is in trying to isolate the first number of the series to use it to determine the length of the list.

Comment: Please show us your code attempts, if you have made any.

Comment: "3.The length of each list must be determined by the value of the first digit of each series." Do you mean the first digit, or the first number? Show an example of a typical input.

Comment: So, what's your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried something here so let me know if this is what you're looking for. It would be better for you to provide your attempt first.

I also want to point out that Lists are for the most part dynamic. You don't have to worry about the size of them like a normal array.

```
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    ArrayList<Integer[]> addIt = new ArrayList<>();
    boolean choice = false;

    while(choice == false){
        String line = sc.nextLine();
        if(line.equalsIgnoreCase("n")){
            break;
        }
        else{
            String[] splitArr = line.split("\\s+");
            Integer[] convertedArr = new Integer[splitArr.length];
            for(int i = 0; i < convertedArr.length; i++){
                convertedArr[i] = Integer.parseInt(splitArr[i]);
            }
            addIt.add(convertedArr);
        } 
    }
```

This is assuming that you are separating each integer with a whitespace. If you are separating the numbers with something else just modify the `split` statement.

The user enters "n" to exit. With this little snippet of code, you store each array of Integer objects in a master ArrayList. Then you can do whatever you need to with the data. You can access the first element of each Integer object array to get the length. As you were confused how to isolate this value, the above snippet does that for you.

**I would also advise you to add your parse statement in a try-catch block to provide error handling for invalid input that cannot be parsed to an integer.**

Answer (score 0):

This is one way of doing it with default arrays.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ScanList {

public static void main(String[] args){
  System.out.println("Array:");
  Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
  String line = s.nextLine();
  String[] nums = line.split(",");
  int[] result = new int[Integer.parseInt(nums[0])];
  for(int i = 0; i<result.length;i++){
    result[i]=Integer.parseInt(nums[i+1]);
  }
  for(int r:result){
    System.out.println(r);
  }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Insert the first series of numbers: ");
    String number1 = input.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Insert the second series of numbers: ");
    String number2 = input.nextLine();

    String[] items = number1.split(" ");
    String[] items2 = number2.split (" ");

    List<String> itemList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(items));
    itemList.remove(0);
    Collections.sort(itemList);
    System.out.println(itemList);


} // End of main method
```